# Getting error while debugging "Debug Error .. Heap corruption detected"

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, exception, visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2005. While debugging code I am getting following error message and after that it is adding break,

> Debug Error !
>    Program :- 
>    Heap Corruption detected : after normal block c#2368 at 0x01d21e30. CRT detected that the application wrote memory after end of heap buffer.

Above error comes on the line

```
delete values[i];
```

where `values` is a vector of `(const wchar_t *)`.

Anybody having idea where this error coming from?

Comment: how did you allocate `values[i]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for sure the result of a buffer write overflow. That means at some place you are writing more chars to a buffer than is allocated for it.

You could use `std::wstring` instead of plain buffers which would eliminate the need for you to manage the buffers for you. Verify each write operation to the buffers.

The overflow is detected on deletion as the heap manager then checks for some pattern at the beginning and the end of the buffers in debug mode.

As others suggested also take care of matching allocation and deallocation:

- new [] -> delete []
- new -> delete
- malloc -> free (which is C and is usually not really of a big use in C++)

Comment: HI @jdehaan :: I later noticed that the contents of values[i] before firing delete operation was vector value("Administrator","FALSE")       then i checked how that memory allocated .. i found this `administrator=new wchar[sizeof(wchar)*2]` then i increased multiplication by 2 to 3 ..4 till 10 and at 10 the heap error gone.now the statement is `administrator=new wchar[sizeof(wchar)*10]`    ... how this solves the error ?  .. Administrator was having value "FALSE" ... does false required that much size ?

Comment: "FALSE" requires at least `6*sizeof(wchar_t)` (5 characters + one zero terminator). If you don't want to worry about memory allcation as I said before, consider using wstring. This will make your life easier and is a more c++ like solution than handling bare character buffers.